# Selenium find element on a dynamic dropdown with scroll (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, scrollbar

I'm playing around with selenium and just lately started to take a look at drop-downs and selecting elements.

For learning Selenium I'm using following site:
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/?sc_selenium=true#featured_dropdown_grid_category

There is a drop-down Grid on which I'm trying to locate an element.
Since the drop-down is dynamic and has a scroll bar then I need to scroll down and locate an element.
Can anyone give me hints how I can locate and select an element on such drop-down?
Let's say I would like to select:

```
Item: contains "Envelopes"
Unit: "EA"
Unit Cost: gather then 0.2
```

Here is my code:

```
            By itemPicker = ByScLocator.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/form/table/tbody[2]/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]");
            driver.findElement(itemPicker).click();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(itemPicker));
            driver.findElement(itemPicker).sendKeys();

            boolean find = false;           
                while (!find) {

                    By menuItems = ByScLocator.xpath("//tr[contains(@id, \"isc_PickListMenu_\")]");
                    List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(menuItems);

                    try {
                        //Verify if all elements still exists in DOM
                        for (WebElement element : all) {
                            element.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
                        }
                    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                        all = driver.findElements(menuItems);
                    }

                    for (WebElement element : all) {
                        List<WebElement> columns = element.findElements(By.tagName("td"));                          
                        String currenlyProcessedItem = columns.get(0).getText();
                        if (currenlyProcessedItem.matches(".*Envelopes.*")) {
                            if (columns.get(1).getText().equals("Ea")) {
                                if (Double.parseDouble(columns.get(2).getText()) > 0.2) {
                                        find = true;
                                    element.click();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (find) { //load another set of list items
                            driver.findElement(By.id("isc_3N")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
                    }


        }
```

The problem is that I'm unable to scroll down the list and identify item I want to select.
Also I don't know if my aproach is optimal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to fix some English issues.  I also marked down your example using 4 leading spaces.  Please provide your code so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can select only one item on this select list.
I think the problem is, that the item you trying to find isn't on the list.
The scroll bar doesn't mater as long as the select list is open.

If you trying just to select an item then this works for the item "Glue UHU Clear Gum 250ml"

```
public class selectItem {
    @Test
    public void selectItem(){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/?sc_selenium=true#featured_dropdown_grid_category");

    // Open select list
    driver.findElement(By.id("isc_1Y")).click();
    // Select row based on a string present
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Glue UHU Clear Gum 250ml')]")).click();

    driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Błażej for your response.
I already tried above but the thing is that this list is dynamic. When you use firebug you will see that only 1st 23 elements are "visible". Once you scroll down the list you will see it refreshed and another set of items are listed. So I would need to run through whole list an see if any of items match what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution below I was able to get elements in the dropdown to resolve.  There are obvious dependencies on timing in the implementation to account for StaleElementExceptions when scrolling the content, but I'm hopeful those can be filtered out with a little more effort.

> If the test doesn't pass for you right away try increasing the
>   'pollingEvery' time to 1/second.  I'm pretty sure that's going to be
>   based on the machine it's being run on, and that will probably need
>   addressing.

```
/** Desired text to find in the dropdown.*/
    String text = "Envelopes Kraft 305 x 255mm (12 x 10) (84GSM)";
    //String text = "Pens Stabiliner 808 Ballpoint Fine Black";

    /**
     * Test to try to find a reference inside a scrollable gwt dropdown container.
     * <p/>
     * Behavior is heavily timing dependent and will take progressively longer as the content in the dropdown increases.
     * <p/>
     * I'm sure this can be optimized, but as a proof it does the job.
     */
    @Test
    public void gwtDropdownWithScrollContent() {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        try {
            driver.get(
                "http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/?sc_selenium=true#featured_dropdown_grid_category");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 240);
            By dropdownTwiddle = By.xpath(".//*[@id='isc_1Y']");
            //Find the combo and hit the twiddle button to expand the options.
            WebElement we = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(dropdownTwiddle)); // Find the drop down
            we.click();

            /*
             * Create a function to use with the webdriver wait. Each iteration it will resolve the table object, find
             * all of the rows, and try to find the desired text in the first <td> field of each row.
             * 
             * If the element is not found, the scroll bar is resovled and the Actions class is used to get a hold of
             * the scroll bar and move it down. Then the wait loops and tries again.
             */
            Function<WebDriver, WebElement> scrollFinder = new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                By optionTable = By.xpath(".//*[@id='isc_3A']");
                By scrollElement = By.xpath(".//*[@id='isc_3N']/table/tbody/tr/td/img");

                public WebElement apply(WebDriver arg0) {
                    WebElement table = arg0.findElement(optionTable);
                    List<WebElement> visibleEntries = table.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr"));
                    WebElement reference = null;

                    for (WebElement element : visibleEntries) {
                        if (ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element).apply(arg0)) {
                            //This happens if the scroll down happens and we loop back too quickly and grab the contents of the table before it refreshes.
                            //Seems to be tied directly to the poll configuration for the web driver wait.
                            continue;
                        }
                        WebElement firstColumn = element.findElement(By.xpath(".//td"));
                        String colVal = firstColumn.getText();
                        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(colVal)) {
                            if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(firstColumn.getText())) {
                                reference = element;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    if (reference == null) {
                        //If the element wasn't found then scroll down and retry the effort.
                        WebElement scrollBar = arg0.findElement(scrollElement);
                        Actions actions = new Actions(arg0);
                        //The offset below may be increased to make a larger scroll effort between iterations.
                        actions.moveToElement(scrollBar).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, 5).release().build().perform();
                    }

                    return reference;
                }
            };
            //XXX:  THIS is the time to increase if the test doesn't seem to "work".
            wait.pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // Setting too low can cause StaleElementException inside the
                                                           // loop. When scrolling down the Object can be refreshed and
                                                           // disconnected from the DOM. 

            Assert.assertNotNull(wait.until(scrollFinder));
        } finally {
            driver.close();
        }

    }
```

Best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

find an element on a dynamic dropdown with scroll (Selenium Java)

```
    {driver.get("https:..............");
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    
    WebElement all = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#searchDropdownBox"));
    all.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
    action.moveToElement(all).perform();

    action.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
            .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
            .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
            .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
            .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
            .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).